# Filter values based on other column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI I'm trying to combine and get the unique values of pages in a new table. I need to filter one of the columns, based on a value of another column in that same table. So i want to do something like

> FILTER(VALUES('Table1'[URL]), 'Table1'[Correct] = "Yes"

But it's not working, because I can only filter based on calculations, not columns.
The complete line that I have now and is working is:

> All pages = FILTER(
> DISTINCT(UNION(VALUES('Table1'[URL]),VALUES(Table2[Complete URL]),
> VALUES('Table3'[URLs]))), [URL] <> BLANK())

How can I add a filter to one of those tables, based on another column of that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace FILTER with CALCULATETABLE:

```
 CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[URL]), 'Table'[Correct] = "Yes")
```

If you need to count the values, just wrap it into COUNTROWS:

```
Measure = COUNTROWS( CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[URL]), 'Table'[Correct] = "Yes"))
```